# React-redux store + pages transitions

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm using `react-redux`, `react-router`,

I'm setting any value: `dispatch({ 'FIRE' });` 
then in reducer:

```
case 'FIRE':
  return {
    isLoading: true
};
```

I cannot understand why when I'm changing pages(I'm clicking on any link), then my store not clears? It's still stores variable `isLoading = true` for all my routes. 
Why?

Comment: Because thats one of the reason of using redux at first place :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because react-router doesn't reload a page. Moreover, its purpose is to change history without page reloading. So the application can use browser history staying Single Page Application. And all scripts, all global stores, which is redux, not reloads too. So if you want to reload your page, you should use usual  instead of router , or fire an event that clears your state when you enter a new page.